# Prove $P \times Q\subset R \times S$ where $P\subset R$ and $Q\subset S$.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-writing

How to prove this subset problem. Can I get some help?

> $P \times Q \subset R \times S$ where $P\subset R$ and $Q\subset S$.

Comment: Learn to use [math.jax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Why are people so mean?  I am a little student

Comment: @Jency: Your original question was rudely worded. No one is being mean.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/conduct

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $x\in P\times Q$.

Then $x=(p,q)$ for some $p\in P\subseteq R$, $q\in Q\subseteq S$.

Thus $x\in R\times S$.

Since $x$ was arbitrary, $P\times Q \subseteq R\times S$.